# VLC Media Player - How do I hide the menu bar?

Tags: vlc-media-player

The one at the top of the window, which has "Media", "Playback", "Audio", etc...

I know I can use the minimal interface, but that also hides the bottom menu. I want to keep the bottom menu but hide the top menu. Preferably, I'd like the top menu bar to appear only whenever I press Alt.

Edit: I am still unable to hide the top menu bar without hiding the bottom one too.

Comment: What os? mac? windows?

Comment: Linux and Windows.

Comment: I have the same issue. In MPC-HC, it's easy to remove under "View", but VLC doesn't seem to have an option for it outside of pressing [CTRL][H] for minimal mode.

Answer (score -3):

It's very simple and essay. You can just follow the screen shot here:

1. [image: System Tray menu]
2. [image: VLC icon right click]

So, please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: How does this even address the OP's issue? Did you read the question?

Comment: Not an answer to OP's question. Just hides VLC completely.